# Disable CSS3 checkboxes on IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have the following CSS for my CSS3 checkboxes. It works perfectly on all modern browsers but doesn't work on IE8 so I would like to disable these special checkboxes and just leave default ones. Is it possible ?

```
   input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1000;
    left:-1000px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height:1px;
    width:1px;
    margin:-1px;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    }

input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox + label.css-label {
    padding-left:17px;
    height:15px; 
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:15px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    font-size:15px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    cursor:pointer;
    }

input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox:checked + label.css-label {
    background-position: 0 -15px;
        }
label.css-label {
    background-image:url('../gfx/checkbox.png');
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    }
```

And some HTML5 code:

```
 <input type="text" size="50" name="dni" value="%dni" class="forminput" style="width: 40px">
<div style="padding-top:10px">Usuwaj tylko zdjęcia pozostawiając artykuły i komentarze&nbsp; 
<input name="czy_tylko_zdjecia" type="checkbox" value="1" %czy_tylko_zdjecia id="checkbox_settings" class="css-checkbox">
<label for="checkbox_settings" class="css-label"></label>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't worth in IE8 because the [CSS3 `:checked` pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) isn't [supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3).

You could target IE8 and overwrite your values with a conditional:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<style>
    input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox {
        position: static;
        z-index: auto;
        left: auto;
        overflow: visible;
        clip: auto;
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

You could also use the [`\9` hack](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/browser-specific-hacks/) to target IE8 and below:

```
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox {
    position: static\9;
    z-index: auto\9;
    left: auto\9;
    overflow: visible\9;
    clip: auto\9;
    height: auto\9;
    width: auto\9;
    margin: 0\9;
}
```